# Prestashop webservices product list pagination

Tags: php, web-services, pagination, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get all the products from a Prestashop using their webservices. I can see there is "limit" parameter available but I couldn't find any information about how to paginate the product list. Is there a page/skip parameter that I don't know of? or if I call '/api/products', do I get all of the products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SQL syntax for limit.

`9,5` will display five element following the first nine.

So if you got 10 elements per page and want to show page 5 you can set your limit to `40,10`.

Here is the code from `classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php`:

```php
//construct SQL Limit
$sql_limit = '';
if (isset($this->urlFragments['limit'])) {
    $limitArgs = explode(',', $this->urlFragments['limit']);
    if (count($limitArgs) > 2) {
        $this->setError(400, 'The "limit" value has to be formed as this example: "5,25" or "10"', 39);
        return false;
    } else {
        $sql_limit .= ' LIMIT '.(int)($limitArgs[0]).(isset($limitArgs[1]) ? ', '.(int)($limitArgs[1]) : '')."\n";// LIMIT X|X, Y
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't have access to the merchant's source code. I am only able to access via webservices.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did there! Sorry I missed the part where limit from url was parsed, duh! I will test this tomorrow and update here. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to get the total product count using the api ? Trying to build a paginator...